# Want to transfer a Minecraft profile to another Microsoft account

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, windows-10

I bought Minecraft for my son a few months ago, using my Microsoft account to set it up.  He has since established a profile and has built a lot of stuff, which he understandably wants to hang onto.  He now wants me to play with him, which (from my understanding) would require me to buy another Minecraft license and set up my own Minecraft profile.  My question is: how can I transfer his Minecraft profile from my Microsoft account to his newly-established Microsoft account?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean *purchases* or do you mean *worlds*. to my knowledge you cant for purchases(including the game), but worlds aren't tied to accounts.

Comment: What platform are you playing on? PC, a console (if so which one? Xbox, PS4, Switch), or mobile device?

Comment: @Penguin on win 10 edition yes. but thats not what the question asks

Comment: @Penguin i know

Comment: @Penguin thats because your comment was about a completely different thing than the poster asks about, as stated in the comment

Comment: @Penguin you are saying purchases are available cross platform, that is *not the same as transferring between accounts*

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119346/discussion-between-topcode-and-penguin).

Answer (score 1):

As stated in another answer, you cannot transfer profile stats, however there are two accounts used in Minecraft on Windows 10. #1 is the Windows Store MS account you have signed in on your PC to purchase Minecraft. #2 is the Xbox/Windows Live account you used to sign in once Minecraft is launched. In your case, you used the same account for both purposes. On a different PC, you can download Minecraft with your Windows Store MS account, but create another Microsoft account for your kid. I suggest creating a proper child account that you can manage to protect them online. Check this link for instructions: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/account-billing/what-is-a-microsoft-family-group-b6280c9d-38d7-82ff-0e4f-a6cb7e659344

The application license is tied to the MS account used on the Windows Store. It doesn't appear to be applied to the PC itself, so in my case, me and 2 kids play using the same application license, but different online accounts. I'm not sure if that is intended to work that way or not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so im going to take it as you are asking if you can transfer worlds? If so, yes you can download it onto a USB drive or onto another computer directly (Or Mobile), if your asking if you can transfer your skin, its possible but I dont know how you would do so other than to remake the skin in a skin creator. If your asking if you can transfer your profile stats  (Kills, Deaths, Worlds Completed, ECT.), No I dont think you can.

Comment: Thanks for answering and pardon my ignorance on terminology and general knowledge as I am new to this.  Good to know about transferring worlds.  So, he would need to get a new license and set up a new profile, and then we could transfer the world over to his machine?

Comment: @ClayWiddifield Yes. If you are playing on PC or Mobile, you can just buy Minecraft again, and transfer worlds. Theoretically, if you are on mobile (and maybe PC), you just need to sign in with a different Microsoft account, but I can not confirm that.

Comment: @ClayWiddifield No problem man. I like helping out the community! If you have any more questions regarding minecraft, Dont be afraid to ask me.